# Vuejs checkbox disable if checked

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

I have 4 checkbox inputs and i want to disable each input if is checked!

And disable all inputs if user checked 2 checkboxes i achive this with v-model length >= 4

```
<div class="form-check">
     <label class="form-check-label">
     <input type="checkbox" value="1" v-model="inputs" disabled="inputs.length >= 4">
        text1
     </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
     <label class="form-check-label">
     <input type="checkbox" value="2" v-model="inputs" disabled="inputs.length >= 4">
        text1
     </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
     <label class="form-check-label">
     <input type="checkbox" value="3" v-model="inputs" disabled="inputs.length >= 4">
        text1
     </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
     <label class="form-check-label">
     <input type="checkbox" value="4" v-model="inputs" disabled="inputs.length >= 4">
        text1
     </label>
</div>
```

What can i do to disable the input checkbox user checked?

Comment: You haven't provided much information, but I believe you want to use `v-bind` for the `disabled` attribute: `<input v-bind:disabled="inputs.length >= 4">` or just `:disabled="inputs.length >= 4"`

Comment: I use <input v-bind:disabled="inputs.length >= 4"> to disable all the inputs and that i'll try to achieve is to disable the checked input

Comment: `:disabled="inputs.length >= 4 || inputs.includes('your hardcoded value')"` where `hardcoded value` is the number you give in `value` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question posting.
I think the `disabled` property of `input` tags should be `:disabled`.

`<input type="checkbox" value="1" v-model="inputs" :disabled="inputs.length >= 4" />`

Hope for your best result.

Thank you.